# Ionic ion-menu-button not working on first load

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

```
<ion-menu-button autoHide="false"></ion-menu-button>
```

At first load it give an error:

```
zone.js:1102 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offsetWidth') ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offsetWidth')
```

If we reload then working fine please help me to fix it...

Comment: Can you please brief a little bit more and share code you've written, it will be easy to get into the issue.

Comment: If i press on menu button .... no nothing happens ... just getting an error ....as we reload the page it work fine ...